# How to remove unwanted favicon

Tags: html, wordpress

So recently I bought a domain and set it up with Wordpress. I then uninstalled WordPress because I just wanted a static landing page. However, for some reason there seems to be this favicon that I didn't add.

So I delete all my files on the site and **it's still there**!

I don't know how to remove it.

Here is a screenshot of the favicon: [image: favicon]

Comment: Maybe cache of your browser

Comment: have you any screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser's caching it.  You can set one like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico" />
```